# Need Library to convert Webm to PCM without Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm currently trying to code an online tuning app in just plain HTML/CSS/JS. What I need is the PCM data coming from `MediaRecorderAPI`'s Webm buffers.

So I either need:

- A library to convert Webm --> PCM (without using Node.js, so probably a minified file)
- OR a library to convert Webm --> WAV, so I can plug it into `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()`

I'm really stuck and confused right now. Here's the code I have right now for this - if I can do it without libraries that would be awesome too.

```js
this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (async e => {
    let blobBuffer = await e.data.arrayBuffer();

    let amplitudeArr = await this.#processAudioData(blobBuffer);                //Error is thrown here
    this.onDataAvailable(amplitudeArr);
});

/**
 * Private method. Given an audio blob, return an Array of its "amplitudes" as a mono channel.
 * @param {ArrayBuffer[]} blobBuffer An array buffer, created from each audio blob 
 * @return {Array[]} An array consisting of the blob "amplitudes"
 */
async #processAudioData(blobBuffer)
{
    const stereoBuffer = await this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(blobBuffer);  //Error is thrown in this line
    return stereoBuffer.getChannelData(0);
}
```

I tried using `decodeAudioData()` to start off, but that does not take Webm data.
I also tried looking into `FFMPEG`, but that's for Node.js and the documentation is very lacking

I tried `wav-audio-recorder` (https://github.com/higuma/wav-audio-encoder-js) and similar libraries so I can do Webm --> WAV --> PCM, it seems they want audioBuffers which I cannot get until I use `decodeAudioData()`.